# Orientation problem for remote tracks on firefox

Tags: agora.io

I have a problem with Agora video SDK 4.4.0 on Firefox.
When a user on IOS SDK 3.4.0 rotates his iPhone/iPad, video is not rotated on Firefox (macOS). But it is ok on safari (macOS) / chrome (macOS), or other IOS device with IOS SDK.
Is there any way to fix this ?
Or, at least, can I detect remote orientation changes (via event, or width / height change, or mediaTrack property, or anything...) to make the rotation myself using some CSS magic ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of firefox, documented [here](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/faq/browser_support?platform=Web).

You can manually set the orientation on iOS. This [page](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/video_rotation_apple?platform=iOS) covers in depth how different modes work. You can use the fixed orientation to manually handle rotation using CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've seen this documentation. But manually set orientation on iOS, or even worse, on android, requires encoding power, generates heat and battery consumption. It can also dramatically slow down video on lower-end android devices to 5-15 fps.
It would be better if agora could pass orientation information somewhere in json objects so we could just add a bit of css in firefox to manually change orientation of the player.